# How to retrieve a value from get_posts()?

Tags: php, get-posts

I'm just trying to retrieve a value of 'title_name' from get_posts and gets the error "cannot use object of type WP_post as array..."
The reason I'm not using have_posts/the_posts is because I want to display the titles in reverse:

```
$arr = get_posts();
$arr = array_reverse($arr);
foreach ($arr as $post) {
    echo $post['post_name'];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Why can't I echo back the field 'post_name' ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your error explains: each post inside your array is an object, not an array. Use `echo $post->post_name;` if you want to display the slug, or use `echo $post->post_title;` to display the title.

Comment: Is there a name for that concept? Is it an array of objects? It's just the first time I stumble upon this. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, it's an array of objects. :)

Answer (score 5):

Each post is an object, which changes the syntax you need to use to access the post name:

```
$arr = get_posts();
$arr = array_reverse($arr);
foreach ($arr as $post) {
    echo $post->post_name;
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

As a side point, a slightly easier (and computationally more efficient) way to get your posts in reverse order is to use this instead of array_reverse()

```
$arr = get_posts(array('order'=>'ASC'));
```

More fun things you can do with get_posts()'s arguments can be found [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) and [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/).